# Can not find data in embedded h2

Tags: hibernate, h2

I am using spring4 hibernate4 with h2 as the embedded database in my application, this is the core configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    <!-- data srouce -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="cn.sw.repository"/>
    <bean id="bussiness_dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${bussiness.jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${bussiness.jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${bussiness.jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${bussiness.jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="bussiness_entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="bussiness_dataSource">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${bussiness.jpa.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.showsql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="cn.sw.model"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="bussiness_transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="bussiness_transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="bussiness_entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

property-placeholder:

```
bussiness.jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
bussiness.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:file:D:/h2db/bus
bussiness.jdbc.username=sa
bussiness.jdbc.password=sa
bussiness.jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Junit-test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/application-config.xml"})
@Transactional
public class ServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @Test
    //@Ignore
    public void create() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            User u = new User();
            u.setUsername("u-" + i);
            u.setPassword("p-" + i);
            userService.save(u);
        }
        SearchResult<User> s = userService.findByCondition(new HashMap<String, Object>());
        assertEquals(10, s.getList().size());
    }


//    @Test
    public void query() {
        SearchResult<User> s = userService.findByCondition(new HashMap<String, Object>());
        assertEquals(10, s.getList().size());
    }
}
```

When I run the test `create` it is succesully, and I can find the file at `D:/h2db/bus`, and the file size will increase accordingly once I run the test.

Then I delete the database file, run `create` once, and make the `create` ignored.

Now there should be 10 records in the table, however when I tried to connect to the database, I can not find the tables like `t_user` and anything else.

And then run the `query` test only, it failed with

`expected:<10> but was:<0>`

What's going on ?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Transactional` annotation on tests work different than in normal code.

On exit of the annotated method it will do a rollback, in order to avoid side effects on other tests:

> the framework will create and roll back a transaction for each test

From http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testing-tx

It looks like you can change this behavior if you want (from the same source):

> If you want a transaction to commit — unusual, but occasionally useful when you want a particular test to populate or modify the database — the TestContext framework can be instructed to cause the transaction to commit instead of roll back via the @TransactionConfiguration and @Rollback annotations.
>
> See transaction management with the [TestContext framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx).

Comment: While once I remove the `Transactional` on the test class, I will get error like `can not find transactional enetity-manager`. What's why I add it.

Comment: @hguser Well you still need the transaction. If you don't want it to rollback, see my latest edit